# Installing boost-python for python3 using brew

Tags: boost, homebrew, boost-python

I'm trying to install boost-python on OSX using `brew install --build-from-source --fresh -vd --with-python3 boost-python` but during the installation, the python detected is 2.7:

```
==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/kp/Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-python-1.66.0.tar.bz2
==> Verifying boost-python-1.66.0.tar.bz2 checksum
tar xjf /Users/kp/Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-python-1.66.0.tar.bz2
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.66.0_1 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.66.0_1/lib --with-libraries=python --with-python=python
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset darwin... tools/build/src/engine/bin.macosxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...
```

On my system, `python` is 2.7 whilst `python3` is 3.5. I wonder why `./bootstrap` uses `--with-libraries=python --with-python=python` rather than `python3`.

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--with-python3` flag isn't supported by `boost-python` anymore. Try installing `boost-python3` instead.